# Replace content with square braces in string

Tags: javascript

I have a string `<input name="product[0][name]" id="product[0][name]" />`

I want to replace `product[0][name]` with `product[1][name]`.

I have tried so many solution to replace string but not able to do exact replaceme.
I tried using `//[`  and similar for other braces it does replace string but with a slash in replacement.

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Comment: Please post your code - we don't write code on demand.  We help fix what you've got :)  ([ask])

Comment: regular expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can easily replace in string using following function

```
var str = '<input name="product[0][name]" id="product[0][name]" />';
var res = str.replace("product[0][name]", "product[1][name]");
```

This is the syntax

```
string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)
```

*searchvalue* could be a value or regular expression

**Note**: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

```
var res = str.replace(/product\[0\]\[name\]/g, "product[1][name]");
```

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to escape in a regexp, you use a backslash "\".
If you want to replace all occurences in the string, you need to use a regexp rather than a string in as replace parameter

```js
var result = '<input name="product[0][name]" id="product[0][name]" />'.replace(/product\[0\]\[name\]/g, "product[1][name]");
console.info(result);
```